# Opamp gain issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-design

I am designing a circuit which has gains of 1, 2, and 3 respectively using a [TL084](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl084) - which is a quad channel amplifier.

Yesterday I was getting stray voltages but I resolved it with pull down resistors. Now i see that the circuits which have gains of 2 and 3 give a gain of 1 only (it acts like a voltage follower.) i

Is there something wrong in my circuit?

By the way:  I am using a 68k pull down resistor. Will it matter if I use high value of resistance for pull down operation?

[image]

Comment: An analog circuit shouldn't need a pull down resistor - those are typically used with digital circuits.  Where did you put those 68k resistors? (Draw them in your circuit diagram.)

Comment: Your data sheet says to place a 0.1-μF bypass capacitors close to the power-supply pins to reduce errors coupling in from noisy or high impedance power supplies - In section 10, also have you grounded your unused gate ? U1D, shouldn't leave it floating (unless datasheet says otherwise)

Comment: @JRE - I'm pretty sure that the unused inputs are left floating. Under these circumstances, a pull-down at the input is an excellent idea.

Answer (score -3):

The circuit looks fine. only thing of which I can think is that there could be an input spike which fried the opamps because they're FET based, but it should work fine just by looking at it.

Comment: This is hardly an answer .. We are just guessing now ?

Comment: Absolutely agree with Sorenp, this space is for answers, not guesses.

Comment: *there could be an input spike which fried the opamps because they're FET* Hmm, I worked with opamps with FET and MOSFET based inputs for decades. **Never** had one blown up by an "input spike". We can thank the **ESD protection** for that. **Guessing** is fine but make it a **comment** not an answer.

Comment: If i try the circuit on the breadboard..it works perfect...But when it comes to the GCB Board ... I have problems..Any solutions?